# some character causing android crash in textview

Tags: php, android

i have android text view and it displays content nicely but i have figured out few characters which causes app to crash.
|  causes app to crash

```
           "बच्चा - "दादी जी 'टें.....' बोलकर दिखाओ |"
       दादी - "टें...|"
      बच्चा - "एक बार फिर बोलकर दिखाओ |"
      दादी - "टें...|"
     बच्चा - "आप कितना अच्छा बोलती हैं, फिर भी मम्मी कल पङोसन से कह रही थी कि पता                              नही बुढिया टें कब बोलेगी...!!!"
```

is there anyway i replace these characters while saving data in my text file, i know i can use php str replace but i dont know all character which will cause problem. after long testing i have found one character which crashes app but $,%#@& all works just fine problem is with this |.
how it is different from &$# etc? i can easily replace while posting data.
i have this in text view ,any idea will be great

```
            JokeString = temptString.replace("\n" , "/-%/");
```

Comment: You were on the right lines, just use a RegEx to remove all characters you don't want. For example, if your app is fully English, you won't be expecting anything other than a-zA-Z0-9 (and possibly symbols)

Comment: Try using htmlspecialchars(). Tell us if it works. ty

Comment: Are you sure its | char? can you provide more php code?

Comment: @Borna yes i have tested and 100% sure that its |  there may be others but i dont know